# Where is dockershim and related logs for debugging kubeflow/pipeline/helloworld

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow-pipelines

I try to run kubeflow samples (pipelines/pytorchjob etc) but it stacks as `ContainerCreating`.

For this purpose, I want to see dockershim and docker logs.
Is there any documentation?

sample code is follows
https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/tree/master/samples/core/helloworld

```sh
kubectl create serviceaccount pipeline-runner
python3 hello_world.py
kubectl create -f hello_world.py.yaml
```

```sh
$ kubectl describe workflow.argoproj.io/my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
Name:         my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
Namespace:    default
Labels:       workflows.argoproj.io/phase=Running
Annotations:  pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline_spec: {"description": "A hello world pipeline.", "name": "My first pipeline"}
API Version:  argoproj.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Workflow
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-04-22T00:11:41Z
  Generate Name:       my-first-pipeline-
  Generation:          3
  Resource Version:    23748
  Self Link:           /apis/argoproj.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/workflows/my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
  UID:                 50acafe4-2254-4dea-865d-7ec03496e523
Spec:
  Arguments:
  Entrypoint:            my-first-pipeline
  Service Account Name:  pipeline-runner
  Templates:
    Container:
      Args:
        echo "hello world"
      Command:
        sh
        -c
      Image:  library/bash:4.4.23
      Name:
      Resources:
    Inputs:
    Metadata:
    Name:  echo
    Outputs:
    Dag:
      Tasks:
        Arguments:
        Name:      echo
        Template:  echo
    Inputs:
    Metadata:
    Name:  my-first-pipeline
    Outputs:
Status:
  Finished At:  <nil>
  Nodes:
    my-first-pipeline-wgkg2:
      Children:
        my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397
      Display Name:   my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
      Finished At:    <nil>
      Id:             my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
      Name:           my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
      Phase:          Running
      Started At:     2020-04-22T00:11:41Z
      Template Name:  my-first-pipeline
      Type:           DAG
    my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397:
      Boundary ID:    my-first-pipeline-wgkg2
      Display Name:   echo
      Finished At:    <nil>
      Id:             my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397
      Message:        ContainerCreating
      Name:           my-first-pipeline-wgkg2.echo
      Phase:          Pending
      Started At:     2020-04-22T00:11:41Z
      Template Name:  echo
      Type:           Pod
  Phase:              Running
  Started At:         2020-04-22T00:11:41Z
Events:               <none>
```

`kubectl logs`are follows

```sh
$ kubectl logs my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397 -c wait
Error from server (BadRequest): container "wait" in pod "my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
$ kubectl logs my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397 -c main
Error from server (BadRequest): container "main" in pod "my-first-pipeline-wgkg2-3423630397" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
```

Answer (score 2):

After you are in the worker nodes you can do `docker ps` to find out `containerid` for the container and then to see logs `docker logs containerid` command should be useful.

Also look at kubelet logs in the worker nodes to see if there is any issue by running command `journalctl -u kubelet.service -f` in the worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the information you seek is in the `kubectl describe` Events section. But in your logs it seems empty. Maybe your pods are not getting scheduled yet?